# from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode gives error while running it on google colab

Tags: python, opencv, importerror, zbar

I am building a barcode scanner. When i write:
`from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode`
It gives the following error:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

```
 ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library
```

I am writing this code on google colab(windows). But when i do
`pip install zbar`
it gives another error and does not install zbar.

Answer (score 0):

[zbar](https://pypi.org/project/zbar/) - is a **package that only provides the interfaces** for interacting with the library. Therefore, **installing the zbar package is not enough** for correct operation. You also **need to install the zbar library**.

Perhaps this command will help you.

```
!apt install libzbar0
```

Before command

```
!pip install pyzbar
```

Source:
[import pyzbar.pyzbar - Unable to find zbar shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217735/import-pyzbar-pyzbar-unable-to-find-zbar-shared-library)