# (MacBook M1):raise ImportError('Unable to find zbar shared library') ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library

Tags: python, python-3.8, zbar

Mac OS X :

```
brew install zbar
```

Install this Python wrapper; use the second form to install dependencies of the command-line scripts:

```
pip install pyzbar
```

I tried these steps but i'm still getting the bellow error

```
File "/Users/something/opt/anaconda3/envs/muenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 136, in zbar_function
    return prototype((fname, load_libzbar()))
  File "/Users/something/opt/anaconda3/envs/muenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyzbar/wrapper.py", line 115, in load_libzbar
    libzbar, dependencies = zbar_library.load()
  File "/Users/something/opt/anaconda3/envs/muenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyzbar/zbar_library.py", line 65, in load
    raise ImportError('Unable to find zbar shared library')
ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library
```

Comment: Facing same problem.

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me. Have a try.

```
mkdir ~/lib
ln -s $(brew --prefix zbar)/lib/libzbar.dylib ~/lib/libzbar.dylib
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/71904987/14882853

Comment: that is all I had to do after all the other commands.

Comment: This a life saver

Comment: Worked like a charm even as of today

Answer (score 0):

The python package `pyzbar` loads the external library `libzbar` using the function `ctypes.util.find_library()`, which looks-up the environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Thus, you can add the following code to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(brew --prefix zbar)/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

For other libraries, `ctypes.util.find_library()` might check `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead.

However, please mind that `libzbar` will still not be found when invoking python from `/usr/bin/env`. This is because the
[System Integrity Protection Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH3-SW1) blocks propagating all dynamic linker environment variables such as `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See also [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568122/why-isnt-dyld-library-path-being-propagated-here).